Gizmo's disappearing when pressing play
I have been playing around with the new Gizmo nodes in Blender 4.3. I am trying to combine them with Simulation Nodes. However, when I press spacebar to play the animation, the Gizmo's disappear and thus I cannot control my animation via them. Would anyone know if it is possible to have Gizmo's always be visible and useable even while playing the animation? Maybe it is a very obvious thing that this happens but just checking if anyone has a solution for this. Thanks in advance!
